# crosshair pointer enter on vuforia unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have successfully enabled 3d object detection through vuforia in Unity. I have attached a crosshair (reticle) at the centre of the screen in screenspace overlay. when the user moves his phone over the 3d object which is produced upon object detection, I want a label to appear when crosshair crosses different parts of the 3d object. I tried many methods including, collision, cursor and reticle. It is not working.
Is there any easy way to implement this so that I can use event trigger pointer enter to make few things happening on the game.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully solved my problem. The solution is using worldspace crosshair.
Most of the crosshairs available in the assets are cemeraspace. therefore using a worldspace corsshair solved my problem. It may be useful to someone in future.